# Form submit, Input:all() not showing all inputs

Tags: forms, laravel

RESTfully, When I submit my form and return Input:all() in the Store method I'm getting only couple inputs not all of them!!

Can anyone help me here to find out why?

and advise me if I've to use Ajax all the time to submit forms, With example please!

Store method in the Controller:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created HOTEL in DB.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(/*AddNewHotelRequest $addNewHotelRequest*/)
{

    if(Request::ajax()) {
        if ( Session::token() !== Input::get( '_token' ) ) {
            return Response::json( array(
                'msg' => 'Unauthorized attempt to create setting'
            ) );
        }
        $input = Request::all();

        $response = [
            'status' => 'success',
            'input' => $input,
            'msg' => 'Hotel created successfully',
        ];

        return Response::json( $response );
    }
    // return Input::all(); //with Request::all() same output
}
```

Form from view "create new hotel"

```
{!! Form::open([ 'data-remote' ,'method'=>'POST', 'action' => 'HotelsController@store', 'class' => 'panel form-horizontal','id'=>'hotelForm']) !!}
<input id="myToken" type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<script> var _CSRT_token = "{{ csrf_token() }} " ;</script>
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="panel-title">Adding New Hotel</span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">

         <!-- / .form-group of Errors -->
         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
                 @include('errors.list')
             </div>
         </div>

        <!-- Hotel Name -->
        <div  class="form-group">
            <label for="hotel_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hotel name *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hotel_name" name="hotel_name" placeholder="Hotel name">
            </div>
            <p class="label label-warning label-tag">Name should be in English</p>
        </div>

          <!-- / .form-group of hotel_details -->
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hotel_details" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hotel Details</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="hotel_details" placeholder="Short description, General information or Some Details about this Hotel" rows="3"></textarea>
              </div>
              <p class="label label-warning label-tag">Details should be in English</p>
          </div>


        <!-- Hotel website -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="hotel_website" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Website *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hotel_website" name="hotel_website" placeholder="http://">
            </div>
        </div>

         <!-- / .form-group of rank -->
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="rank" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rank</label>
             <div class="col-sm-1">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rank" placeholder="Boutique or 4">
             </div>
         </div>

        <div class="panel colourable">
            <div class="panel-body">Prices</div>

             <!-- / .form-group of single_price -->
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="single_price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Single price</label>
                 <div class="input-group col-sm-1">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control room-price-group" id="single_price">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <!-- / .form-group of double_price -->
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="double_price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Double price</label>
                 <div class="input-group col-sm-1">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control room-price-group" id="double_price">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <!-- / .form-group of extra_bed_price -->
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="extra_bed_price" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Extra Bed price</label>
                 <div class="input-group col-sm-1">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">€</span>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extra_bed_price">
                     <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="facilities" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Facilities *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select id="facilities" class="col-sm-8 form-controljs-example-basic-multiple" name="facilities"  multiple="multiple">
                    <optgroup label="Free">
                        @foreach($facilities as $facility)
                            @if(!$facility->is_surcharge)
                                <option class="" value="{{ $facility->id }}">{{ $facility->name }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Surcharge">
                        @foreach($facilities as $facility)
                            @if($facility->is_surcharge)
                                <option value="{{ $facility->id }}">{{ $facility->name }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="panel colourable">
            <div class="panel-body">Address</div>

            <!-- / .form-group of Country -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <select id="country" class="form-control" name="country" >
                        <option></option>
                        @foreach($countries as $country)
                        <option value="{{ $country->id }}" phone_code="{{ $country->phone_code }}" >{{ $country->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <p  class="help-block helperQuote">Begin by choosing your country.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- / .form-group of Region -->
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="region" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Region *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <select id="region" class="form-control" name="region">

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / .form-group of city -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city" class="col-sm-2 control-label">City *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <select id="city" class="form-control" name="city">

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / .form-group of rank -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zip" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Zip Code</label>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="34600">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- / .form-group of city -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hotel Address *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Street name, number of building floor ...etc">
                </div>
                {{--<p class="label label-warning label-tag">Address should be in English</p>--}}
            </div>

            <!-- / .form-group of map -->
            {{--GOOGLE MAPS--}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="map" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Location *</label>
                {{--<a href="#" id="initMap" class="btn" onclick="initializeMap();return false;">Initialize Map</a>--}}
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div id="map-canvas" class="" style="width: 100%; height: 350px !important;">
                    </div>
                    <p id="markerPosition" class="help-block"><i>Drag the pin to the position of the hotel </i></p>
                    <p id="lat" class="help-block">Latitude: 41.0694</p>
                    <p id="lng" class="help-block">Longitude: 29.0043</p>
                    <input  id="latitude" type="hidden" value="37.7577">
                    <input  id="longitude" type="hidden" value="-122.4376">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div> <!-- End of Address Panel -->



        <!-- Hotel tel -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country_code" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Country Code *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="country_code" name="country_code" placeholder="+90">
            </div>
            <label for="country_code" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Phone *</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____">
            </div>
            <label for="extension" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Extension</label>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension" name="extension" placeholder="3">
            </div>
        </div>

        <ht/>
         <!-- / .form-group of status -->
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="status" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status *</label>
             <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <select id="status" class="form-control" name="status"   >
                     <option value="0">Suspended</option>
                     <option value="1" selected>Draft</option>
                     <option value="2">Published</option>
                 </select>
                 <p  class="help-block helperQuote"><strong>Suspended:</strong>Trash,<strong>Draft:</strong>Default,<strong>Published:Online</strong></p>
             </div>
             <p class="label label-warning label-tag">Only Published Hotels will be online!</p>
         </div>

        {{--@if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())--}}
         <!-- / .form-group of publisher -->
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="publisher" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Publisher *</label>
             <div class="col-sm-2">
                 <select id="publisher" class="form-control" name="publisher" >
                     @foreach($publishers as $publisher)
                         <option value="{{ $publisher->id }}">{{ $publisher->name }} ({{$publisher->type}}) </option>
                     @endforeach
                 </select>
             </div>
         </div>
        {{--@endif--}}




        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-1">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-flat"><span class="btn-label icon fa fa-plus-circle"></span> Add Hotel</button>
            </div>
            <div id="loader" class="col-sm-1" style="display: none;"><img src="/assets/images/plugins/bootstrap-editable/loading.gif" alt="loading regions" /></div>
        </div> <!-- / .form-group -->

        </div>
{!! Form::Close() !!}
```

The output is like this:

`{"_token":"PWKknjx5S9u8m98ApGDXYKqaTyF7aFZDaye9uYPm","hotel_name":"City Loft","hotel_website":"http:\/\/www.cityloft.com.tr\/","facilities":"23","country":"6","region":"3344950","city":"783593","country_code":"+355","phone":"(123) 123-1231","extension":"3123","status":"1","publisher":"1"}`

Comment: So, _which_ inputs are missing? What's the actual response and the expected response?

Comment: @SimonSvensson, Output like this:

`{"_token":"PWKknjx5S9u8m98ApGDXYKqaTyF7aFZDaye9uYPm","hotel_name":"City Loft","hotel_website":"http:\/\/www.cityloft.com.tr\/","facilities":"23","country":"6","region":"3344950","city":"783593","country_code":"+355","phone":"(123) 123-1231","extension":"3123","status":"1","publisher":"1"}`

Comment: For example Hotel Details is missing along with prices.. and others

Comment: That looks totally wrong, your code returns an json-array with, amongst other stuff, the text "Hotel created successfully". Your output does not contain that. Have you checked that the input is correct? I see several of missing name-attributes on your input-elements, so they wouldn't be sent in the post.

Comment: I'm filling out the form, and I guess this answering your question about "**Have you checked that the input is correct?**"
Yes I know a lot are missing

Comment: I mean the input sent in your post, the data sent to the server. You could use Firebug in Firefox or Developer Tools in Chrome to check the data being sent.

Comment: @SimonSvensson Thanks a lot buddy It was because of me, accedintaley forgot name attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72314/discussion-between-kawsara-mike-and-simon-svensson).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot **name attribute** for Hotel Detail and Price and might be more

```
<textarea class="form-control" **name="hotel_detail"** id="hotel_details" placeholder="Short description, General information or Some Details about this Hotel" rows="3"></textarea>
```

Comment: Idiot me! I'm so sorry I've been stuck in this for like 10 hrs :(